# How to make an OAuth Authentication from IP

Tags: javascript, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

I have a .NET Web Api. I want to consume from webs and Mobile Apps, but I don't want the user to sing in or create an acount. Can I make an authentication from IP or domain name or something similar?

I tried to implement a Basic and Oauth Authentication, but don't want to place the plain text with the user and password in javascript webs cause everyone can see it and I can't find a secure way that don't need to ask the user to loggin.

Do you have any ideas?

Edit:
I know that I can use google or facebook account or my own users database... the problem is that i don't want the user to insert their loggin parameters and i am searching a secure alternative to restrict the use of the app.

Comment: Many people have dynamic ip. What happens if someone's ip changes? What happens if someone wants to login from a different computer? Facebook uses logins, do you think they are not secure?

Comment: No, i know that loggins are secure, I know that I can use google or facebook account or my own users database... the problem is that i don't want the user to insert their loggin parameters and i am searching a secure alternative to restrict the use of the app..

Comment: If this is your app or website, then who are you afraid of?

Comment: You can use TLS client certificates for your clients if you know them all.